# Why Android OS does not create a new instance of an singleTop activity if my app in the background?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, launchmode, android-task

My app has two activities: A and B. A - is the main activity (default for launch), it has action `android.intent.action.MAIN` and category `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`, and A activity has overridden `lanchMode="singleTop"`, it means that if we trying to launch activity A and A is not the top of the task, then OS will create a new instance of A and put it on top.

Steps:

- launch activity A from apps menu (click on the app icon)
- click the button in activity A screen to launch B (now activity stack looks like A -> B)
- press the home button to see the apps menu again and to minimize the app
- click on the app icon again to launch my app

Result: opened activity B (stack looks like A -> B)

So my question is why OS do not create a new instance of A if my app in the background with task stack looks like A -> B (B places on top, A and B not finished, they in onStop state) and just open the current stack when I tap on app icon from apps menu (that tap send the intent to my app with Launcher intent, and Launcher is described in activity A which has launch mode singleTop)

I think it suppose to open new instance of A (with stack A -> B -> A) because of A has `lanchMode="singleTop"`. Seems like if the app had activities in the background (in `onStop` state) and it was opened with the same intent as the first time, then Android OS just show the current app task, but I can not find any proof of that.

Comment: Yeah that is the right behavior, read the life cycle of an Activity here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @ShailendraMadda Thanks! But could you, please, provide a quote with the proof of this behavior?

Comment: When you move from Activity - A to Activity - B then Activity A is going to back stack. Then if you click the Home button then your Activity-B is still there right? If you finish the activity then only it will launch Activity-A otherwise it opens the last Activity which is B in your case.

Comment: @ShailendraMadda Yes, I found it empirically, but I need some proof of that behavior. Could you, please, provide a quote from documentation?

Comment: Check it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onpause

Comment: @ShailendraMadda Sorry, but I can't find any relative information in the onPause section of activity lifecycle docs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224310/discussion-between-shailendra-madda-and-alexey-nikitin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour actually has nothing to do with the launch mode of the `Activity`. Actually, in this case, Android isn't launching any `Activity`. You would see this if you added logging or set a breakpoint at `onNewIntent()` which would be called in the case where Android wanted to launch the `Activity`, saw that there was already an instance on top of the stack in the task, and routed the new `Intent` to the current instance by calling `onNewIntent()`.

What is haooening here, when the user taps the app icon on the HOME screen, is that, before launching any `Activity`, Android looks to see if there is already a task in the background that was started with this same `Intent` (in this case, ACTION=MAIN, CATEGORY=LAUNCHER, COMPONENT=ActivityA). If it finds a task that was started with the same `Intent`, it simply brings that task to the foreground in whatever state it was in (exactly as it was when it was moved to the background) and that's it. It doesn't launch any new `Activity`, it does not call `onNewIntent()` on the topmost `Activity`.

This is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) (although it is easy to miss):  where it says:

> The device Home screen is the starting place for most tasks. When the
> user touches an icon in the app launcher (or a shortcut on the Home
> screen), that app's task comes to the foreground. If no task exists
> for the app (the app has not been used recently), then a new task is
> created and the "main" activity for that app opens as the root
> activity in the stack.